# Which version of bodoni is this?

Tags: font-identification

I don't know if this is the correct forum for this type of question, but could anyone help me with identifying this font?

I know it's almost certainly part of the Bodoni family but I am unsure of the exact type. Any help is appreciated!

I have tried a few of the online services, but I can only whittle it down to the Bodoni family and not more specific, one or two of them wern't even close...
[image: Book Title]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a period piece - and that period would be around the 1940s/1950s. So it might just not be available as an electronic font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very much like [Bodini Pro Book](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/bodoni/pro-book/)

[image: PRINCIPLES]
[image: QUANTAM]
[image: MECHANICS]

Comment: Hey Aasim, can you edit your answer and add a screenshot of the font? It will help futureproof for link rot later on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a set of "modern" serif fonts. This was the style popular in the nineteenth century and on into the twentieth for scholarly printing, but every printing equipment company cut their own variation, so you won't find a perfect match. A condensed Bodoni revival is right for the heading.

For the body text - this is a different end of the "modern" style to Bodoni's work and imitations of it, more even and with less stroke contrast. Century Expanded or Excelsior are probably the closest designs in this style with revivals available now, or if money is no object Shinntype's [Scotch Modern](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/shinn/scotch-modern/) or Hoefler's [Surveyor](https://www.typography.com/fonts/surveyor/overview/) (both amazing fonts, but you pay for what you're getting). Basically, pick and choose one with the general colour of impression that matches what you want to see. As a note, the original book would probably have looked more spindly than this - scanners often add weight to make the text clearer to read, but if you're planning to imitate this on paper printout does too.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a nice answer! Would you know how I can get these fonts in LaTeX?

Comment: All of those are commercial font families, so the answer involves money! I assume they'd work fine in LaTeX as OTF fonts, but I don't know.